# How can I get items from multiple lists in a certain order?

Tags: python, list

This is sort of confusing me because what I seem to need to do is get an item from one list, an item from another list, etc. and then *go back* to the first list and get another item, etc. I'm having trouble figuring out how to revisit the same lists multiple times.

Here's the list:

```
table_data = [['apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'banana'],
              ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'David'],
              ['dogs', 'cats', 'moose', 'goose']]
```

I need to print out this data in the following format:

```
apples    Alice    dogs
oranges     Bob    cats
cherries  Carol   moose
banana    David   goose
```

Thanks!

Comment: Start with a `zip(*table_data)`.

Comment: Thanks! That should be the start I needed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) will generate an iterator that groups elements by their position (index) in the passed iterators. In your case passing `*table_data` will "expand" table data into 3 lists that then can be passed to `zip`

```
for fruit, person, animal in zip(*table_data):
    print(fruit, person, animal)
```